# Are WPF Application Settings automatically saved by default?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, application-settings

Are WPF Application Settings **automatically** saved by default when exit?

I just added a boolean to my application settings (by default is setted to **false**). I want to set it to true when application is running and next time when I open it again, to be **false**. I don't want to save my application settings. I want to be static for that boolean.

It is saving **automatically**?

When I used to work with VB.NET Winforms, there was a setting in Application tab, named "**Save my.settings on shutdown**". But, how is in WPF?

I use Visual Studio 2012, Vb.NET WPF application

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to make it an application setting?

Why not just a static variable in the app?

Comment: No, you would have to call `Save()`, e.g. in the MainWindow's `Closed` event handler.

Comment: It is complicated to explain. I have just to many windows in my project and I need an universal place (like my settings) to temporary store a Boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are settings saved automatically? No, you have to explicit invoke the Save method upon each settings class.

Since you mention that you have multiple windows, then i think the quick and dirty way would be to override the OnExit Method in App:

```
Class Application
    Protected Overrides Sub OnExit(ByVal e As ExitEventArgs)
        MySettings.Default.Save()
        MyBase.OnExit(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Woups.. Didn't see you requested VB. I've changed the answer code sample to VB.